# Proving $x\left(1+e^x\sin^2x\right)^{-1}$ is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How does one prove that $x\left(1+e^x\sin^2x\right)^{-1}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,\infty)$?

The source of this problem includes a hint to compare this function with one of the form $\left(1+x^2\right)^{-1}+\text{a simple function}$, but I don't see how to do that either.

Comment: Show that this function is less than $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ except near $x=0$ and on very small intervals of the form  $(k\pi-r_k, k\pi+r_k)$, where $r_k < k^{-4}$ for sufficiently large $k$; on these small intervals $f< k\pi+1$ and its integral $< k^{-2}$, the sum of them is finite.

Comment: How to show that? Differentiating e.g. $x\left(1+e^x\sin^2x\right)^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ doesn't seem to help, and nor do standard inequalities for $e^x$ and $\sin x$, since after taking the reciprocal, they go in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a continuous function, so we just need to show that it is integrable on $[N, \infty)$ for some (large) $N>0$. In the following we assume $x\geq N$, we will decide what is $N$.

For any $k\pi\geq N-2\pi$, choose $r_k>0$ so that $e^{k\pi} r_k^2=(k\pi)^4$, that is,
$$
r_k=e^{-k\pi/2}(k\pi)^2.
$$
We can pick $N$ big so that $k\pi\geq N-2\pi$ implies
$e^{-k\pi/2}(k\pi)^2<k^{-3}$.
Thus
$$
r_k<k^{-3}.
$$
Now for any $x\geq N$ so that $x\notin (k\pi-r_k, k\pi+r_k)$ for any $k\pi\geq N-2\pi$, we find $n$ so that $n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq  x\leq n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$; so $|x-n\pi|\geq r_n$, so
$$
1+e^{x}\sin^2x\geq 1+e^{n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2r_n\geq 1+c^2e^{n\pi}r_n^2=1+c^2(n\pi)^4.
$$
Here we used the well known fact that $\frac{\sin r}{r}> c=\frac{2}{\pi}$ when $|r|<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus if $N$ is sufficiently big (note $n\pi\geq N-2\pi$), we have
$$
1+e^{x}\sin^2x\geq 1+(n\pi+\pi/2)^3.
$$
In particular, since $x\leq n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, we see
$$
1+e^{x}\sin^2x\geq 1+x^3.
$$
In conclusion, for $x\geq N$ outside every $(k\pi-r_k, k\pi+r_k)$, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{1+e^x\sin^2x}\leq \frac{x}{1+x^3}.
$$
Thus
$$
\int_{[N, \infty)-\cup_k (k\pi-r_k, k\pi+r_k)} f(x)dx<\int_N^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^3}dx<\infty.
$$

On $(k\pi-r_k, k\pi+r_k)$, we estimate simply $f(x)\leq \frac x1 \leq k\pi+r_k$, so
$$
\sum_k \int_{k\pi-r_k}^{k\pi+r_k}f(x)dx< \sum_k (k\pi+r_k)\cdot 2r_k\leq \sum_k 2(k+1)\pi k^{-3}<\infty. 
$$
The summation is over those $k$ with $k\pi\geq N-2\pi$. Add these two estimates we get
$$
\int_N^\infty f(x)dx<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could I ask what's the motivation for the steps at the start? Is it a standard argument for these sorts of problems? As I don't know how I ever would have thought of it.

Comment: The function $f$ is not bounded, that is, $f(x)=x$ near $k\pi$, these are the "spike" parts. But away from these the function is "tame", behaving like the integrable function $cxe^{-x}$. We need to treat them separately.

Comment: I see. Where you go from $1+e^{n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2}r_n$ to $1+c^2e^{n\pi}r_n^2$, where does the $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ go? Shouldn't it be $1+c^2e^{n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}r_n^2$? (Though it doesn't make much of a difference I suppose, as we still have $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}c^2(n\pi)^4 \geq \left(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3$ for sufficiently large $n$.)

Comment: Oh, we can just let $c$ be a new constant, say $e^{-\pi/4}$ times the old $c$... in many papers constants like $C$ changes from line to line.